# Office365/Azure API to query to get status of security controls?

Tags: azure, api, office365

We're trying to build a web app to scan our clients tenancies and identify what users have

- MFA enabled (or disabled)
- Legacy Protocols disabled (ie: POP3, IMAP, etc)

And from the tenancy, what are the settings for

- Password policy
- Are audit logs enabled?

We seem to be able to get most these things by using PowerShell commands, but wanted to build this into a web application that is given access to the tenancy (delegated or authorised).

Is this possible?